# Rails hourly cron jobs using Whenever fails to run hourly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever

On Redhat, using Whenever. My cron jobs fail to run hourly. I need help as to why.

Schedule.rb

```
every 1.hours do
  rake "deathburrito:all", :environment => "development"
  rake "bamboo:all", :environment => "development"
  rake "jira:grab_data", :environment => "development"
end
```

Crontab -l

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/qadashboard && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake deathburrito:all --silent'

0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/qadashboard && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake bamboo:all --silent'

0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/qadashboard && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake jira:grab_data --silent'
```

Can anyone help me? I am not even sure what else I should be checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle` will have to be in that subshell's path. Try specifying a full-blown `/usr/bin/bundle` (or whatever it is).

Comment: So if I follow you I would change this bundle exec rake bamboo:all --silent to /usr/bin/bundle/bundle exec rake bamboo:all --silent?

Comment: yes. unless you can gurantee that /usr/bin/bundle will be in that particular shell's path, you'll have to use a full path.

Comment: Should have thought of this before... I needed to specify the rake location too...

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
MAILTO=your@email.com
```

to your crontab. Then enjoy the error reports from cron.

If that won't solve the issue, post the error report here.

Comment: Nice... I was unaware of that. That will be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Append log to config/schedule.rb

```
set :output, "/var/log/cron"
```

and create this file 'cron' in /var/log and give it write permission.

Execute

```
  bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
  sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

To see the logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/cron
```

will give you more insight on the error.